# How to execute a Node command in a Kotlin/JS project

Tags: kotlin-js

Kotlin/JS maintains a local Node installation, used by Yarn, etc.

Is there a way to execute commands via that installation, without using a Gradle plugin that downloads another one?

Answer (score 2):

The task [kotlinNodeJsSetup](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/40d19b50c5a8d953aaabd93da1064df4d3c44b8d/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/targets/js/nodejs/NodeJsSetupTask.kt#L43) exposes the destination of the Node installation.

Using this task, it is possible to create a NodeJS task:

```
tasks.create<Exec>("yourTask") {
    dependsOn(":kotlinNodeJsSetup")

    val kotlinNodeJsSetup = rootProject.tasks["kotlinNodeJsSetup"] as org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.nodejs.NodeJsSetupTask
    workingDir = File(kotlinNodeJsSetup.destination, "bin")
    commandLine(
        "node",
        "yourScript.js",
        "arg1",
        "…",
    )
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the [Slack thread](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/C0B8L3U69/p1629282839299000?thread_ts=1629279395.297900&cid=C0B8L3U69), there is no `bin` subfolder on Windows for the executable (`node.exe` is directly there). You might need to define the work dir differently based on OS, unless there is a better way

Comment: It's possible to leverage Gradle's [Task Configuration Avoidance](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/task_configuration_avoidance.html) by using `val yourTask by registering(Exec::class) {` for the declaration. Also, had to use `"./node"` instead of `"node"`.

Comment: Configuration already finalized for previous property values